# Play mp3 file form android raw folder getting error Uri is <URL suppressed>

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I need to play a sound from raw folder in my android application what I am trying to do -

```
    Uri alert = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.ring_tone);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) / 7.0)),
                Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) / 7.0)));

        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
            }
        }, 1000 * 60);
```

but I am getting an exception `E/MediaPlayer﹕ Uri is  <URL suppressed>
 D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is <URL suppressed>`

**I am adding the LogCat as per request-**

`06-27 11:00:00.118  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
 06-27 11:00:00.118  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
 06-27 11:00:00.118  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
 06-27 11:00:00.358  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 97K, 37% free 12543K/19779K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
 06-27 11:00:00.378  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 27.252MB for 6551056-byte allocation
 06-27 11:00:00.408  26004-26008/com.altaoferta.reunio D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 28% free 18939K/26183K, paused 7ms+4ms, total 28ms
 06-27 11:00:00.438  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio E/MediaPlayer﹕ Uri is  <URL suppressed>
 06-27 11:00:00.478  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is <URL suppressed>
 06-27 11:00:00.568  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
 06-27 11:00:00.588  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
 06-27 11:00:00.588  26004-26004/com.altaoferta.reunio D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so`

Answer (score 0):

Change URI declaration to

```
Uri alert = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/ring_tone");
```

or use

```
URI.getScheme() or URI.getPath().
```

Comment: @bumba and try to add extension. I mean `"/raw/ring_tone.mp3"` for ex.